# How can I call functions in a native C library generated by Kotlin/Native from C#?

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, kotlin-native

Given the following C API generated by Kotlin/Native:

```
#ifndef KONAN_bar_H
#define KONAN_bar_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
  /* Service functions. */
  void (*DisposeStablePointer)(bar_KNativePtr ptr);
  void (*DisposeString)(const char* string);
  bar_KBoolean (*IsInstance)(bar_KNativePtr ref, const bar_KType* type);

  /* User functions. */
  struct {
    struct {
      void (*foo)(const char* string);
    } root;
  } kotlin;
} bar_ExportedSymbols;
extern bar_ExportedSymbols* bar_symbols(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}  /* extern "C" */
#endif
#endif  /* KONAN_bar_H */
```

how can I access the native function `foo` from C# using P/Invoke?

I have been going through [Marshal API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx), and have tried several different ways to marshal the native object (like `Marshal.PtrToStructure` after returning an `IntPtr` from the `extern` call), but I know I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to marshal native objects, and things are even more complex when given a nested struct like above.

I have been going through [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-Csharp-Chapter-1-Introducing-Marsh.aspx) trying to learn how to marshal complex objects, but this particular use-case doesn't seem to be covered.

After some hours trying to squeeze anything our of this, here is the current state of my application:

```
public class TestExtern
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer( CallingConvention.StdCall )]
    public delegate void foo( string @string );

    [DllImport( "bar" )]
    private static extern BarSymbols bar_symbols();

    private void Start()
    {
        var barSymbols = bar_symbols();
        var kotlin = barSymbols.kotlin;
        var root = kotlin.root;
        var fooDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<foo>( root.instance );
        fooDelegate( "Testing" ); // Access Violation
    }

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct BarSymbols
    {
        public Kotlin kotlin;
    }

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct Kotlin
    {
        public Root root;
    }

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct Root
    {
        public IntPtr instance;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm not familiar with Kotlin/Native, but if there is any way to specify that it should produce a flat API for C code, you should definitely use that. As it stands, the generated API is much too complicated; the `bar_ExportedSymbols` structure is nothing more than a bag of functions -- it doesn't need to be defined as a structure at all.

However, going forward with the code we have, you need to define delegates that correspond to the native function pointers.

```
public class NativeMethods
{
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public delegate void DisposeStablePointer(IntPtr ptr);

  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public delegate void DisposeString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str);

  // this assumes that bar_KBoolean is defined as an int
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  public delegate bool IsInstance(IntPtr pRef, IntPtr type);

  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public delegate void Foo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string str);

  [DllImport("KONAN_bar.dll", EntryPoint = "bar_symbols")]
  public static extern IntPtr BarSymbols();
}
```

The next thing to do is to define a managed struct to hold the function delegates. The native struct needlessly contains the nested `root` and `kotlin` structures, which don't do anything useful. This definition should work, unless there are struct padding issues that are specific to your compiler/platform, which you will have to resolve yourself.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ExportedSymbols
{
  public NativeMethods.DisposeStablePointer FuncPointerDispose;
  public NativeMethods.DisposeString FuncStringDispose;
  public NativeMethods.IsInstance FuncIsInstance;
  public NativeMethods.Foo FuncFoo;
}
```

A simple program to test access to the `foo` function:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    IntPtr p = NativeMethods.BarSymbols();
    ExportedSymbols es = (ExportedSymbols)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(ExportedSymbols));
    es.FuncFoo("Testing");
  }
}
```

Since this structure is nothing more than a set of function pointers, you will presumably store it in a static variable somewhere that will last the life of the application. If this involved a structure with data members that was allocated and needed to be freed at some point, you would store the pointer `p` so that you could pass it to a library function that would release the allocated memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unaware of a way to produce a flat object. It produces a struct representing the package structure of the application (e.g. `com.xaerodegreaz.somepackage`), and in this particular output I'm simply testing by writing a function in the `root` package.

Comment: Thanks -- your code works when making a standard console application. Strangely, though, it crashes Unity (where I was doing all of my initial testing). I had tried similar methods before, but it always crashed. I went back to trying those methods I used before in a console application and they now work, too. Seems like I could have saved a lot of frustration, by trying this in a standard console application first. At least I would have known the fault was somewhere in Unity.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use @konan.internal.CName("topLevelFunctionName") annotation to export your function as top level C function, and use it as usual, so for code like:

`@konan.internal.CName("topLevelFunctionVoidFromC")
fun topLevelFunctionVoid(x1: Int): Int`

following C code will be produced:

`int topLevelFunctionVoid(int x1);`

See https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/backend.native/tests/produce_dynamic/simple.